# Convert delimited string to xml in C# using LINQ

Tags: c#, xml, linq, parsing

I am using System.Xml and have a textbox with a string delimited by `\r\n`. The string is basically a list of serial numbers that I want to format as XML to pass to a stored procedure to run a validation.

An example of the string as it appears now:

```
"ABC123\r\nDEF456\r\n"
```

I am thinking it would be a very basic XML Schema, for example

```
<SerialNumbers>
    <Serial>ABC123</Serial>
    <Serial>DEF456</Serial>
<SerialNumbers
```

What is the basic idea to accomplish this so I have something to springboard off of??

Comment: Create your XML structure and loop over your string.Split() results. Check here for XML creation documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx

Comment: You're *not* trying to parse this as XML - you're trying to *format* the data as XML, effectively. There are two steps: 1) Split your current string into separate serial numbers; 2) create an XML document from it. Which are you having issues with?

Comment: Thanks guys. Do you have any suggestions for making this question better fit the rules? I'd like this to be available and helpful for others. I will take a look at the help center.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using LINQ it would be quite simple, after splitting the serials to a list/an array:

```
var doc = new XDocument(
    new XElement("SerialNumbers",
        (from x in serials select new XElement("Serial", x))
    )
);
```

Comment: I'm getting a strange error with this line. The name 'doc' does not exist in the current context'. I know usually this means the variable you're trying to use hasn't been declared so I'm a little confused why I'm receiving this. Any ideas?

Comment: http://puu.sh/a5kF6/13cf9aec31.png Here's what the code looks like.

Comment: @Dezryth you are missing the type declaration! either use `var doc` or `XDocument doc` to get the code compiling...

Comment: Ah yep I finally figured that one out. Felt pretty stupid on that one! Thanks for the help!